# how are governments approaching the "bathroom laws" globally?

Tags: government, policy, lgbt+

[The discussions on the various bathroom laws in the usa](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15875/trump-on-trans-bathroom-issue-libertarian-or-conservative) got me thinking:

Q: how do other countries or governments manage folks' desire to go into the bathrooms of opposite sex?

In the United States, the federal government stepped in under president Obama and then stepped out under president Trump to mandate certain actions. some states mandated certain ways, and then some districts mandated still others.

It would be helpful to see how other countries handle the same challenge from a policy perspective.

Comment: I guess most countries don't have a law. And I'm not aware of any large-scale problems because of this lack-of-a-law. So the federal government stepping out is in line with the rest of the world. No citations, though, as it's hard to find citations about a lack of a law.

Comment: -1 Your question is loaded out of the gate. The law has to do with gender identity...not "a desire to go in the opposite sex bathroom"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a faulty pemise

Comment: This question is legitimate.  The argument is that *gender identity* would allow someone who claims a particular identity, but is physically the other gender to use the bathroom of the claimed identity.

Comment: There are about 200 countries in the world (depending on how you count). This question is pretty broad.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is focused on Germany ("other countries" seems a bit broad).

There are no laws regarding the issue, but the government [declared](http://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btd/18/024/1802482.pdf) that students should be allowed to use bathrooms which match their gender identity. They also suggested that unisex bathrooms should be made available if possible.

Regarding private businesses, the answer linked above refers to guides such as [this one](https://www.berlin.de/lb/ads/_assets/schwerpunkte/lsbti/materialien/tia/tia_broschure_reader_trans_im_job_bf.pdf) from the senate administration of Berlin, which says that trans people should be allowed to use the bathroom matching their gender identity. It also suggests unisex bathrooms if possible.

The anti-discrimination office also [says](http://www.antidiskriminierungsstelle.de/DE/ThemenUndForschung/Geschlecht/Themenjahr_2015/Trans/trans_node.html) that trans people are protected by the AGG, which is a law regarding discrimination in various aspects (discrimination by an employer, by the government, by private businesses, etc).